# loading a html page after php content is loaded

Tags: php, html, load

i am including a html page(say b.html) to a html page(a.html) using jquery ,the b.html page contains 6 links in it ..i want to display them below the php content of a.html,but before php content loads b.html is displayed .how can i get html page below php ??

```
<script>(a.html)
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$("#includedContent").load("/templates/default/property/tab.html");
});
</script>
in html page (a.html)  
<div id="includedContent"></div>
```

Comment: in /templates/default/property/tab.html,tab.html is b.html

Comment: place the php code after loading a.html as php runs first..

Comment: php goes to client as html; if you want a delay of 'that' html, you can use jquery to control when is shown

Comment: this is not proper description

Comment: Where is the definition of this `loadContent()` function? I wean where you have defined it? Or I would like to know what code this `loadContent()` contains. Or do you have any idea what you are doing or you are trying to achieve?

Comment: loadcontent() function is not needed ,so i m removing from code here ,document.ready, loads the tab.html thats all ..i just want to know how do i display this tab.html below the php content of the other html page

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be resolve via ajax

```
<script>(a.html)
$(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '/templates/default/property/tab.html',
                          //or b.html 
              data: form_field,
              success: function(d){

                  $('#includedContent').html(d);
              },

          });

});
</script>
in html page (a.html)  
<div id="includedContent"></div>
```